# How do devices discard packets?

Tags: network, networking

My question is fairly simple, I'm just not entirely sure what information I'm looking for.

Let's say that a host receives a packet that is supposed to be for another host, and discards it.  Where is the packet discarded?  Is this done physically in the NIC, or does this happen at a higher level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packets are layer-3 datagrams, so the layer-2 frame encapsulating the layer-3 packet would need to have the host layer-2 address to get into the host network stack, where the packet would be discarded as not matching the layer-3 address configured on the host.